# Is there a number format that omits redundant decimal points?

Tags: output-formatting

Mathematica has several number formats such as [`ScientificForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScientificForm.html), [`EngineeringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EngineeringForm.html), etc.  Are there any that can be configured to omit a redundant decimal point, or alternatively: work on exact numbers?

I want either

```
myForm[2.*10^10]
```

> $2\times 10^{10}$

or

```
myForm[2*10^10]
```

> $2\times 10^{10}$

(Of course for `2.5*10^10` the decimal point would be required.)

With `ScientificForm`, I get

```
ScientificForm[2.*10^10]
```

> $2.\times 10^{10}$

```
ScientificForm[2*10^10]
```

> $20000000000$

I can piece the result together with strings or `HoldForm`, but my question is: is there a builtin solution?

---

Why do I think there may be a builtin way?  Because of the tick marks here:

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 10^10]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

It is however possible that this formatting is done by the front end and isn't available in the kernel.

What is this needed for?  Precisely for tick labels.  I know that a reasonable workaround for this application is using $2.0\times 10^{10}$, and I have been using that in the past. This time I want simply $2$ instead of $2.0$ or $2.$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use the [`NumberFormat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberFormat.html) option of [`ScientificForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScientificForm.html).

With

```
nf = With[{m = ToExpression@#1},
   Row[{If[PossibleZeroQ[m - Round[m]], ToString@Round[m], #1],
     Sequence @@ If[#3 == "", {}, {"×", #2^#3}]}]] &
```

The arguments to `NumberFormat` are strings so you have to convert to test.

Then

```
v = {2.*10^10, 2.000001, 6885.45559^2};
ScientificForm[v, NumberFormat -> nf]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

## Update

Using `StringTrim` from comments and also added spacing.

```
nf = Row[{StringTrim[#1, "."], 
    Sequence @@ If[#3 == "", {}, {Spacer[3], "×", Spacer[3], #2^#3}]}] &

ScientificForm[v, NumberFormat -> nf]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Could we simplify this to simply `Row[{StringTrim[#1, "."], "\[Times]", Superscript[#2, #3]}] &`?  A problem both with this and with your solution is that the spacing around the operator $\times$ isn't correct.

Comment: @Szabolcs That does not work for numbers like `2.0001`.  You end up with `2x10`.

Comment: @Szabolcs See update for spacing and using `StringTrim`.